# What log level are request logs?

Tags: logging, server

There are 7 log levels: `off`, `fatal`, `error`, `warn`, `info`, `debug`, `trace`.

I'd like to log user requests to a server, what log level should request logs be?

What's a common practice here?

**Info** or **debug**?

Answer (score 1, accepted):

> I'd like to log user requests to a server

Then presumably, you want to *know* this information. You don't generally run systems in debug mode in the normal course of business, rather you do so for a short time to gather information needed for a specific, limited, purpose.

So I would say, you want `info` level rather than `debug`. I wouldn't go any further than that since a user logging in is not really something you need to be warned about, nor should it be considered an error (fatal or otherwise).